# ignore words and remove case sensitive and space to match

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, parsley.js

I would like to ignore 'regularexpression' but also ignore space and Uppercase so if someone types 'regular expression' or 'reguLarExpression' it will still match and ignore. Can you please help.

```
^(?!(regularexpression)$)[a-zA-Z](?:[ ()'.\-a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z()])
```

I use this code in parsley.js:

```
data-parsley-pattern="^(?!(regularexpression)$)[a-zA-Z](?:[ ()'.\-a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z()])"
```

I have a set of words that I want to ignore but they don't have spaces or lower case. So, I need to cover the variations like in the example above.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of data which you are matching against?

Comment: i use this code with parsley.js data-parsley-pattern="^(?!(regularexpression)$)[a-zA-Z](?:[ ()'.\-a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z()])"  and i have a set of words that i want to ignore but they don't have spaces or lower case. So i need to cover the variations like in the example above.

Comment: @Alinacdn So, you want to use a pattern that matches a string that does not contain some phrases with and without a space between? Can you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: Or do you mean that beside the negation, the whole string should only contain letters, spaces, `(`, `)`, `'`, `.` and `-` and should start with a letter and end with a letter or parentheses?

Comment: ok so this is for a form where people are restricted to use the words or 2 words from the list but they can submit any other word except the ones in the ignore. The problem is that the ones inside ignore the 2 words are written as 1 word. Like in my example: ignore words: regularexpression. But people would submit regular expression with a space or maybe with upper case etc. And i want to match the ignore. Excpet the ignore list they can use any other word/words so that s why i have the rest of the syntax to allow the rest of the words outside the ignore list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your pattern, you want the whole string to only contain letters, spaces, `(`, `)`, `'`, `.` and `-` and should start with a letter and end with a letter or parentheses. Beside that, you are trying to negate the match if the string contains `regular expression`, `regularexpression`, `RegULar ExpressioN`, etc.

In **parsley.js**, you may use both *string* and *regex literal* patterns, i.e. `data-parsley-pattern="\d+"` = `data-parsley-pattern="/^\d+$/"`. Note that string patterns are anchored by the framework automatically, while with the regex literal notation you need to add the anchors to make sure the whole string matches the regex.

As JavaScript regex does not support inline modifiers, **you need to use the *regex literal notation with `/` as delimitiers**.

The `data-parsley-pattern` will look like

```
data-parsley-pattern="/^(?!.*regular\s*expression)[a-zA-Z](?:[ ()'.a-zA-Z-]*[a-zA-Z()])?$/i"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zHgt3B/1). **Note the `/.../i`: the `i` is the case insensitive flag here**.

To add more exceptions, keep on adding `(?!.*my\s*new\s*phrase)`, or use an alternation inside a single lookahead, `(?!.*(?:regular\s*expression|my\s*new\s*phrase))`. Also, use word boundaries if you need to match these phrases as whole words, e.g. `(?!.*\b(?:regular\s*expression|my\s*new\s*phrase)\b)`.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*regular\s*expression)` - no match if there is `regular` + 0 or more whitespaces and then `expression` after any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `(?:[ ()'.a-zA-Z-]*[a-zA-Z()])?` - an optional sequence of

  - `[ ()'.a-zA-Z-]*`  - 0+ ASCII letters, space, `(`, `)`, `'`, `.` or `-`
  - `[a-zA-Z()]` - an ASCII letter or `(` or `)`
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/parsleyjs/2.0.0-rc5/parsley.js"></script>

<form id="parsley" data-parsley-validate>
  <input type="text" name="the_name" id="the_id" data-parsley-pattern="/^(?!.*regular\s*expression)[a-zA-Z](?:[ ()'.a-zA-Z-]*[a-zA-Z()])?$/i" required>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I do not know how to combine these together but someone will know but here are the Regex Patterns I would use.

1. Whitespace and Character Casing
2. For the word Regular Expression.

   `^[A-Za-z.\s_-]+$`

   `(?:regularexpression|regular expression)`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to guess, maybe this expression might be closer to what you have in mind:

```
(?i)^(?!(regular\s*expression)$)[a-z](?:[ ()'.a-z-]*[a-z()])$
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lU8STP/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/lU8STP/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: JavaScript regex does not allow the use of inline modifiers.

Comment: @Alinacdn What help did you get from this answer? The solution is not working, nor helpful, it just does not work in JS.

Comment: Your solution works perfect, why do you say it doesn't work, i have tested it